# Binding Particular Data from Entity Model and User Input into GridView using C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a table in the database with multiple columns, but I only want to extract the ItemId and Price into my GridView table.

Here is the user flow: user will enter an ItemId and Qty in the textboxes in the webform. That ItemId will be searched in the database. Once the ItemId is found, bind that ItemId and the respective Price, and also the user's Qty input into the GridView.

Below is my code in the code-behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            gridViewData();
            GridView1.DataSource = dtPO;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
    }

    private void gridViewData()
    {
        dtPO.Columns.Add("ItemId", typeof(string));
        dtPO.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
        dtPO.Columns.Add("QtyReorder", typeof(int));
        dtPO.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(decimal));
        dtPO.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));
        Session["dtPOInSession"] = dtPO;
    }

    protected void AddItemButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LastADEntities1 context = new LastADEntities1();
        ItemList item = new ItemList();

        var itemDescription = context.ItemLists.Where(x => x.ItemId == ItemIdTextBox.Text).Select(x => x.Description);
        var itemPrice = context.ItemLists.Where(x => x.ItemId == ItemIdTextBox.Text.ToString()).Select(x => x.Price).ToList();

        DataRow dr = dtPO.NewRow();
        dr["ItemId"] = ItemIdTextBox.Text;
        dr["Description"] = itemDescription;
        dr["QtyReorder"] = Convert.ToInt32(QtyReorderTextBox.Text);
        dr["Price"] = itemPrice;
        dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToInt32(itemPrice) * Convert.ToInt32(QtyReorderTextBox.Text);
        dtPO.Rows.Add(dr);

        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I am using C# and an entity model .edmx

Below is my partial webform code

" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Supplier]">

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="157px" Width="736px" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemId" HeaderText="Item ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description"  HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="QtyReorder" HeaderText="Quantity" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" />
                <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I have a System.ArgumentException: 'Column 'ItemId' does not belong to the table.'

Please help to give pointers or suggestions for fixes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using DataBind() in AddButton Method,make another function that fill gridview data as such bind gridview and call it in the else statement of (!isPostBack) just like to be

```
if(!isPostBack)
{
  //add columns to gridview
  ........................
  ........................
}
else
{
    fillData();
    ............
    ............
    //OR try to DataBind() here and fill through addButton Method
}
```

I Hope so it would work, not tested.